# Which way to use Delayed_Job for scheduling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a list auction items in a sql db that end (come due) at a specific time and I'm looking for the proper approach toward using (Delayed::Job.enqueue) to trigger a method when a given auction finishes.

1) Use a worker for every auction which is loaded into memory when the auction starts

2) Use one worker that is loaded when the web app starts which queries the db periodically to see if any auctions have ended.

Are there any better approaches than the 2 listed above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `run_at` and separately queue each item to wake up at their end time when it's added to the database.  Then you'd only need one worker, which wouldn't get any work to do until something's ended.  (Or, more accurately, you would want N workers, where N is the number of simultaneous closings you expect, or want to handle.)

```
auction.delay(:run_at => auction.ending_at).post_end_work
```

If you can't queue the auction when it's added to the database (if it's added by something that doesn't have access to your `DelayedJob` for instance) then you'll want to use a single worker who sweeps the database for `ending_at` values within the last X amount of time, where X is the run-frequency of your worker.  (And an index on `ending_at`.)

I'd strongly recommend against using separate workers for each auction.

Comment: Cyberfox, is this what you are recommending against? It seems the follwing is the way email is sent at a later date. Any reason not to do it this way?               Delayed::Job.enqueue(Finish.new(auction), 3, 7.days.from_now)